# Sync IdeaVim shortcut handler settings

Tags: jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin, ideavim

I use the [IdeaVim](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/164-ideavim) plugin in various JetBrains products, mostly Idea and RubyMine. I am also working on several PCs, and set up a new dev environment quite often.

I can keep most of my settings and installed plugins in sync quite well across installations by using my JetBrains Account and the Settings Sync plugin, but the Vim Emulation settings added by IdeaVim are not synced.

[image: Shortcut conflict settings]

This means that I have to reconfigure the shortcut conflicts every time I use a new JetBrains IDE or move to a new machine - not too much work, but I would still like to avoid it.

I am aware that the IdeaVim plugin saves its settings (including the ones mentioned above) in the file `~/.IntelliJIdea2018.2/config/options/vim_settings.xml`, but this file is not synced by Settings Sync. I am also aware I can use `.ideavimrc` to customize shortcuts (and I can sync that using some dotfile manager) but to my knowledge there is no way to configure the shortcut conflicts settings in that file.

Is there a way to sync the Vim shortcut handler settings as pictured from one machine to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE Settings Sync plugin doesn't allow to sync settings of plugins such as IdeaVim. According to the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html), it syncs only the following settings of the IDE itself:

> IDE themes, keymaps, color schemes, system settings, UI settings, menus and toolbars settings, project view settings, editor settings, code completion settings, parameter name hints, live templates, code styles, and the list of enabled and disabled plugins

Editor settings don't include custom plugins that work with the editor. The only thing about plugins that is synced is the list of the plugins itself.

Feel free to file a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA about synchronizing settings of plugins.